# How can I cache component data in React so it doesn't re-render on every load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, performance, caching

I am using React native and on one of my screens I have a toggle component. The component has 2 options and clicking on them renders different data. I've noticed performance is not bad on ios but awful on Android and I want it to be good on both (obviously)

The props and state are not changing every time I toggle so it should just be able to render it super fast? the second screen is where I'm seeing more of an issue. but is essentially a fairly big array, rendering a list with lists inside each one.

I've tried using this: `export const CachedPreviousGames = React.memo(PreviousGames)` where `PreviousGames` is the component in question

However, when I toggle back and forth I see that the component console.logs are fired, I also see the console.logs inside the `.map` functions are called. is this expected? I was hoping `React.memo` would only re-render if the props changed?

Is there any other caching strategy I can do to fix this to make it more performant?

MORE DETAILS

so the two components are `League` and `Previous Games` where I'm basically mapping over data from my redux store in `League` and in `Previous Games` it takes a prop of `games` and maps over that.
it's quite an expensive function, verified by the fact that when I replace the map with just a `Text` string, the toggle appears to happen much faster. When I say props don't change I mean, exactly that. `Previous Games` loads up with fresh data on app load but it never changes (until this happens again). i.e. every time I toggle, the props remain constant

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail with your code sample? Trying to understand how toggling is happening without changing at least one of props or state.

Comment: Don't confuse rendering with function running. React engine desides, if some component should be rerendered. But the component as a function runs every time the props/state is changed. This does not necessarily mean rerendering.

Comment: @azundo I have added more stuff in `More Details` of course, let me know if you still need anything further

Comment: @Fide good point. is there not a strategy to combat this, I would assume it's quite a regular pattern

Comment: one way I've seen so far is faking the toggling by having display as a prop. and then I just pass in none, or flex depending on the toggle state. it looks like it's toggling but in reality it's just showing and hiding. which has improved performance

Comment: What you describe sounds like a good use for `React.memo` so something is not working right. If the only prop for `Previous Games` is the `games` array and `React.memo` is not working then your `games` prop must be changing. Again, hard to know exactly what's going on without some example code showing the component that is being run too often and the source of its props.

Answer (score 0):

**If you need more control on when to skip render using `React.memo`, you should write a custom compare function.** You can write your own custom function to do comparison or use from some library like `isEqual` from lodash.

[React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) will skip re-render when `props` are same i.e. **shallow equal**.

> If your component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

> React.memo only checks for prop changes. If your function component wrapped in React.memo has a useState, useReducer or useContext Hook in its implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change.

> By default it will only **shallowly** compare complex objects in the props object. If you want control over the comparison, you can also provide a custom comparison function as the second argument.

#### Default behavior (shallow compare)

Example, `Child` and `Parent` both are re-rendering even when values are "same":

```js
const ChildMemo = React.memo(Child)

function Parent() {
  console.log('parent rendering ...')
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([1])
  return <ChildMemo value={value} setValue={setValue} />
}

function Child({ value, setValue }) {
  console.log('child rendering ...')
  return <button onClick={() => setValue([1])}>{JSON.stringify(value)}</button>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('myDemoDiv'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="myDemoDiv"></div>
</body>
```

#### Custom behavior (custom/deep compare):

---

Example, `Child` is not rendering when values are "same":

```js
const ChildMemo = React.memo(Child, (prevProps, props) => {
  return _.isEqual(prevProps.value, props.value)
})

function Parent() {
  console.log('parent rendering ...')
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([1])
  return (
    <ChildMemo value={value} setValue={setValue} />
  )
}

function Child({ value, setValue }) {
  console.log('child rendering ...')
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setValue([1])}>{JSON.stringify(value)}</button>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('myDemoDiv'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="myDemoDiv"></div>
</body>
```