# Mapping through local JSON file with large data in react takes some time to load. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, performance

I am using react with TypeScript. I am mapping through a JSON file in react. It takes a second to render all the data in the browser. I'm using functional components. Here is the code. Please help me optimize the render time in the browser.

```
import users from "../data/users.json";

const Users:React.FC=() => {

  const displayUsers=users.map((item){
   return(
    <p> {item.username} </p>
    <p> {item.location} </p>
    <img src={item.avatar}/> 
   )
  })

  return(
    <div className='container'>
     <div className='user'>
      {displayUsers}
     </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:** With your current implementation, `users.map` will be executed at each render of the component.

You can optimize it using `useMemo` hook:

```
import users from "../data/users.json";
const Users:React.FC = () => {

  const mappedUsers = useMemo(() => {
    return users.map((item) => {
      return( <>
        <p> {item.username} </p>
        <p> {item.location} </p>
        <img src={item.avatar}/> 
      </> )
    })
  }, [])
  
  return(
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='user'>
        {mappedUsers}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now the `map` function will be called only once when component mounts.

If you want to re-calculate the data using `map` based on some dependency change, you can put it in dependency array `[]` of `useMemo`.

If `users` data is comping through `props` of some parent component, you can use `React.memo` to avoid re-rendering of (this) child component when `props` are same. Here is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66612904/2873538) with demo for `React.memo`.